# How do I use the inject method to calculate the balance instead of what I have now?

Tags: ruby

In the balance function, I am trying to calculate the balance using the inject method instead. Tried the documentation but couldn't get it..

I am new to Ruby and programming so any help would be appreciated..

```
class BankAccount
      attr_reader :name

      def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @transactions = []
        add_transaction("Beginning Balance", 0)
      end

      def credit(description, amount)
        add_transaction(description, amount)
      end

      def debit(description, amount)
        add_transaction(description, -amount)
      end

      def add_transaction(description, amount)
        @transactions.push(description: description, amount: amount)
      end

      def balance
        balance = 0.0
        @transactions.each do |transaction|
          balance += transaction[:amount]
        end
        return balance
      end

      def to_s
        "Name: #{name}, Balance: #{sprintf("%0.2f", balance)}"
      end

      def print_register
        puts "#{name}'s Bank Account"
        puts "-" * 40

        puts "Description".ljust(30) + "Amount".rjust(10)
        @transactions.each do |transaction|
          puts transaction[:description].ljust(30) + sprintf("%0.2f", transaction[:amount]).rjust(10)
        end

        puts "-" * 40
        puts "Balance:".ljust(30) + sprintf("%0.2f", balance).rjust(10)
        puts "-" * 40
      end

    end
```

Comment: Is all that code needed to describe your problem?

Comment: More resources: http://railspikes.com/2008/8/11/understanding-map-and-reduce

Answer (score 1):

Your example is great, as it's very easy to change the loop you have to an inject call:

```
def balance
  @transactions.inject(0.0) { |balance, transaction| balance + transaction[:amount] }
end
```